# Open a Python file with command line arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, command-line

NOTE : I don't know if this has been asked before, but I couldn't find what wording would be used for asking this question

I am creating a python file, and inside it needs to have a name of a file.
What I want is when you put `python Compiler.py <Filename>` in the command line, it takes the filename and uses it in the python file.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you want compile a python code?

Comment: @SaeedBolhasani Python is interpreted, not compiled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
someVariable = sys.argv[1]
```

This will take the first element after the file name and store it in the variable.

```
someOtherVariable = sys.argv[2]
```

will take the second element, and so forth.

```
python Compiler.py firstArg secondArg NthArg
```

Note: You will need to `import sys` to use the `sys` module.

Comment: The terminology to search on google is "how to pass script/process input arguments in python".They are managed in all programming languages

Comment: @MadPapo This would be more appropriate as a comment on the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sys.argv` to get the args that are passed to the script.

```
import sys
open(sys.argv[1], 'w').write('hello world')
```